# Mostrar todas las combinaciones al multiplicar todos los numeros de una matriz

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Partinos de una matriz de tres columnas y un numero indefinido de filas.Los números de la primeroa y segunda fila pueden ser cualquier número, y la tercera coluna es siempre una columna de 1. Pongamos que el numero de filas es 5, y tenemos por ejemplo la matriz M:

```
2 2 1
3 4 1
9 8 1
6 6 1
7 2 1
```

Quiero saber **cuales** son las **combinaciones** C(numero de elements totales, número de filas). En este caso C(15,5) y el resultado que salen de multiplicar las distintas combinaciones posibles. Por ejemplo:

Combinacion1: 2*3*9*6*7; y al multiplicarlo da:  2268

Combinacion2: 2*4*8*6;  y al multiplicarlo da: 384

Comment: No se entiende bien la pregunta. Muestras una matriz, pero se da a entender que hay varias ("Todas las matrices"). El producto en cuestión ¿es de varias matrices o de los elementos de una matriz? Y ¿qué es eso de "todas las combinaciones"?  El ejemplo que pones tampoco se entiende ¿qué son las `i` y  `j` primas? ¿De dónde sale el 24?

Answer (score 1):

Bien, por lo que tengo entendido te equivocaste al dar la segunda "combinación" puesto que en realidad sería: 2x4x8x6x2=768

El problema en sí, está muy confuso, no aclaras si se deben multiplicar los elementos entre sí no siguiendo un orden posible o sólo multiplicar según la columna, tampoco aclaras qué exactamente debe dar como resultado la función.

En fin, no sé si esto te va a ayudar pero bueno:

```
def C(matriz):
    k=0;
    comb_res=[];
    for k in range(len(matriz[k])-1): # largo de las columnas ignorando la columna de los 1
        sub=[];
        elem=[];
        i=0;
        for i in range(len(matriz)): # largo de las filas
            elem.append(matriz[i][k]); #guardo los elementos de la columna k y la fila i
        r=1;
        l=0;
        sub.append(elem); # agrego los elementos
        for l in range(len(elem)): # multiplico los elementos guardados
            r=elem[l]*r;
        sub.append(r); # agrego el resultado 
        comb_res.append(sub);  # agrego los elementos y el resultado de multiplicar
    return comb_res;

matrizA=[[2,2,1],[3,4,1],[9,8,1],[6,6,1],[7,2,1]];
prueba=C(matrizA);
i=0;
print(prueba)
```

Y devuelve:

> [[[2, 3, 9, 6, 7], 2268], [[2, 4, 8, 6, 2], 768]]

Básicamente toma todos los primeros elementos de la primera, segunda, ..., enésima fila y los guarda. Luego, recorre los elementos guardados y los multiplica. Luego, guarda los elementos guardados y el resultado de multiplicarlos en un vector y así con todas las columnas. Luego, retorna el vector creado.